# Exposed date select list in descending order

Tags: views

Using Drupal 7 Views with exposed filter on date, the select list is working fine. Problem is that the list is always in ascending order, for example 2000:2014, but we want it the other way round, like 2014:2000 so that the recent years are closer at hand.

I don't mind if the solution (changing date list to descending order) is affecting every select list of the whole site. Preferably if don't need to change code.

Comment: There is some information on how to achieve this here https://drupal.org/node/426920

Comment: I saw also https://drupal.org/node/206127 thanks both.

Comment: Just thought perhaps BEF @Mikekeran (Better Exposed Filters) would work out?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via hook_form_alter().

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form['#id'] == 'FORM-UNIQUE-ID') {
    $form['field_MY_FIELD_value']['value']['#process'][] = date_select_desc_element_process;
  }
}
```